# Turn off internet for VM while hitting webserver on VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machines

I have a Virual Machine running in VMware Workstation on my laptop.

The VM is running Windows Server 2008.  It has an IIS server running on it.

I would like to be able to remove the internet connection from the virutal machine but continue to use the internet on my laptop.  I would also like to be able to hit the webserver on the vm.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Settings -> Network Adapter -> Host Only

[image]